# How do I make my array change when clicking theme changing button?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a word guessing game and I have a few variables to select the targetted word from an array of words. But I'm also trying to implement theme choosing for the game as well. However, when I click on the theme selector button, it doesn't seem to be updating the targetted word at all. Please have a look at my code and help if you are able to!

```js
/**
 * This array will contain the words that will be used as answer the of game.
 * The words will be coming from runGame function when user select theme of the game.
 */ 
let targetWords = []

/**
 * This array will take on the one word from the tagetWords array so the user can guess.
 * This should change with the theme
 */
const targetWord = runGame()

/**
 * Logic for the game to select which theme the target word needs to be
 */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

    for (let button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            let gameTheme = this.getAttribute('data-type');
            runGame(gameTheme);
        })
    }
    runGame();
})


/**
 * Starts the game and select which targetWords list to use based on what the theme user selected.
 */
function runGame(gameTheme) {
    // if the user select fruit theme, the target word will be from this array
    if (gameTheme === "fruit") {
        targetWords = ["acorn", "carob", "dates", "gourd", "grape", "lemon", "limes", "mango", "melon", "olive", "peach", "pears", "plums", "prune", "salak"];
    }

    // if the user select vegatable theme, the target word will be from this array
    if (gameTheme === "vegetable") {
        targetWords = ["azuki", "basil", "beans", "caper", "chard", "dulse", "enoki", "grain", "groat", "maize", "morel", "pinto", "ramps", "thyme", "wheat"];
    }
    console.log(targetWords)

    const chosenWord = targetWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)];
    return chosenWord;

/**
 * Starts the app and let user able to click or press key to enter their guess.
 */
function startGame() {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleMouseClick);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    runGame();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Foodle</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="title-container">
        <h1>FOODle</h1>
        <button><i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i></button>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <div class="alert-container" data-alert-container>
    </div>
    <div class="theme-area">
        <button data-type="fruit" class="btn">Fruit Words</button>
        <button data-type="vegetable"class="btn">Vegetable Words</button>
    </div>
    <div data-game-area id="game-area">
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-keyboard id="keyboard-area">
        <button class="key" data-key="Q">Q</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="W">W</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="E">E</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="R">R</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="T">T</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="Y">Y</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="U">U</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="I">I</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="O">O</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="P">P</button>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <button class="key" data-key="A">A</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="S">S</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="D">D</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="F">F</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="G">G</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="H">H</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="J">J</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="K">K</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="L">L</button>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <button data-enter class="key large">Enter</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="Z">Z</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="X">X</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="C">C</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="V">V</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="B">B</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="N">N</button>
        <button class="key" data-key="M">M</button>
        <button data-delete class="key large">&#10094;&#10094;</button>
    </div>

    <!------------ Font Awesome Script ------------>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2c7a82bc8a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The blank targetWords array should take on either "fruit" words or "vegetable" words depending on which theme the user selected. But at the moment its not doing that

Comment: When you create the variable `const targetWord = runGame()`, you aren't passing any value into the function. `function runGame(gameTheme)` expects a value

Comment: You are also missing a closing bracket `}` for your function `runGame(gameTheme)`. Also, please edit your post and trim your code into a [mre].

Comment: Whenever you call **runGame** you need to pass it the theme you want to use. If you don't pass any theme, it doesn't know what theme you want to use.  You can always set a default theme. Or require a theme to be chosen before running **runGame**

Answer (score 0):

```
const targetWord = runGame()
```

This will call the `runGame` function with no arguments. Log the `gameTheme` parameter value to see what's going on.

You also call `runGame` in many other places, with no arguments as well.